# Java Spring Rest Template not posting JSON as String

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-rest

I am trying to query the ElasticSearch database by using its Rest API. I am building a client in Java using Spring restTemplate.

I have first tried the request using postman client and it works ok.
For example:

**On postman**:

```
 Url : http://localhost:9200/index/_search
    Headers: Content-Type : application/json
    Body: Raw
    Body content: {
        "_source": ["_id", "message"],
         "query": {
         "match_all": {}
   }
 }
```

And in Java Class:

```
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);
  ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = restTemplate
      .exchange(url, 
  HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

The exception is that 500 Internal Server error. I am able to do a simple get request but having the issue while posting this json data in the post request. What could be the reason for Internal Server error?

Here is the stack trace printed on console.

```
21:10:59.718 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://localhost:9200/index/_search"
21:10:59.738 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, */*]
21:10:59.740 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{"_source": ["_id","message"], "query": {"match_all": {}}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@6522d847]
21:10:59.967 [main] WARN org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:9200/index/_search" resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error); invoking error handler
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:279)
```

Here is the image from eclipse debugger indicating the error in more detail.
[image: Eclipse Debugger Stack Trace]

Comment: Could you paste the error please?

Comment: The error is this:
On eclipse in the exception object i get is this: "org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array." and on detailedMessage it says that 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. Need more info in the stacktrace

Comment: I have added the stack trace and its image as well that is being shown on eclipse. Can you try running some sample code related to this on your end?

Comment: Thanks for letting me paste stack trace. Because i just noticed that the JSON request that was being sent to the server in the stack trace doesn't have the closing braces. being put it there solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: cool. no problem!!

Comment: From the log details looks like you are posting an array instead of object. Writing [{"_source": ["_id","message"], "query": {"match_all": {}}]  This should probably just be Writing {"_source": ["_id","message"], "query": {"match_all": {}}